# Maximum sum leaf to root: wrong output

Tags: python, data-structures, tree, binary-search-tree

I ma trying to solve GeeksforGeeks problem [Maximum sum leaf to root path](https://practice.geeksforgeeks.org/problems/maximum-sum-leaf-to-root-path/1):

> Given a Binary Tree, find the maximum sum path from a leaf to root.

My code:

```
class Solution:
    def maxPathSum(self, root):
        #code here
        maxi = float('-inf')
        def dfs(cur,cursum):
            nonlocal maxi
            if not cur : return 
            if not cur.left and not cur.right:
                maxi = max(maxi,cur.data + cursum)
                return 
            cursum += cur.data
            dfs(cur.left,cursum)
            cursum -= cur.data
            dfs(cur.right,cursum)
        dfs(root,0)
        return maxi
```

I tried the above code considering the fact the cumulative sum (cursum) is updated by adding the current node's data before traversing to its left and right children. After traversing the children, the cumulative sum is reverted by subtracting the current node's data

But the solution is not working.

For instance, for this input:

```
    1
   / \
  2   3
```

... my code returns 3, when the correct answer is 4 (path 1 to 3).

What is my mistake?

Answer (score 0):

> After traversing the children, the cumulative sum is reverted by subtracting the current node's data

This is the correct idea, but you did not implement it correctly. The problem is that you need to have `cur.data` included also for the traversal in the *right* subtree. So you perform the subtraction too early.

Change:

```
        cursum += cur.data
        dfs(cur.left,cursum)
        cursum -= cur.data
        dfs(cur.right,cursum)
```

to:

```
        cursum += cur.data
        dfs(cur.left,cursum)
        dfs(cur.right,cursum)
        cursum -= cur.data     # <--- moved
```

Now it will work. You can even avoid changing the `cursum` variable, and just pass an *expression* as argument to the recursive calls:

```
        dfs(cur.left,cursum + cur.data)
        dfs(cur.right,cursum + cur.data)
```